# ajax session changes (without posting)

Tags: ajax, session

I have 2 files:
widget.php (this file get requests from ajax.php and change selectbox values.

ajax.php (this file lists room numbers when room type selected on widget.php)

when I change selectboxes sql query is always changing through ajax

```
$searchsql = SELECT room_ID FROM rooms WHERE roomtype_id = ".$room_id."
```

But in widgets.php if I use $searchsql as a session It won't remember latest changes. How can I make widget.php to change sessions through ajax instantly when roomtype is changed.
I hope its clear for you. I will try to send codes to somewhere like codepad.org.